# Cannot see any data from Azure Data Factory connecting to SAP Open Hub

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, etl, sap-bw

**I'm trying to connect the SAP BW using SAP Open hub. The connection (Integration Runtime) is successful, however, when I create a dataset, I get the following error when I click on preview data. Even, if I pass this, I still get the same error, running my pipeline.**

> Error: Failed to invoke function /SAPDS/RFC_READ_TABLE2 with error:
> SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcAbapRuntimeException, message: An error
> has occurred while parsing a dynamic entry., stacktrack: at
> SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcConnection.ThrowRfcErrorMsg() at
> SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcConnection.ReadBytes(Byte* buffer, Int32
> count) at SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcConnection.ReadRfcIDBegin(Int32&
> length) at SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcConnection.ReadUpTo(RFCGET
> readState, RfcFunction function, RFCID toRid) at
> SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcConnection.RfcReceive(RfcFunction
> function) at
> SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcFunction.RfcDeserialize(RfcConnection
> conn, IRfcIOStream stream) at
> SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcFunction.RfcCallReceive(RfcConnection
> conn, IRfcIOStream stream, RFCID rid) at
> SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcFunction.Invoke(RfcDestination
> destination) at
> Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.SapRfcHelper.SapRfcClient.InvokeFunctionInternal(IRfcFunction
> function, Boolean initStatefulSession, Boolean checkForErrors) at
> Microsoft.Practices.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0()
> at
> Microsoft.Practices.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy.ExecuteAction[TResult](Func`1
> func) at
> Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.SapRfcHelper.SapRfcClient.InvokeFunction(IRfcFunction
> function, Boolean initStatefulSession, Boolean checkForErrors). An
> error has occurred while parsing a dynamic entry. . Activity ID:
> b4bf2aae-df6f-4c3f-acd2-1cd9844b4f3f

[image]

Comment: This is one of the many issues with the ADF SAP connector. https://www.aecorsoft.com/blog/2019/1/31/use-adf-and-ssis-to-copy-data-from-sap-bw-the-comparison-of-options

Comment: Your error message indicates that it is resulted from the connection with SAP open hub table,not ADF inside error. Are you able to access SAP open hub table successfully without ADF? Or could you please share some configurations in ADF dataset here?

Comment: We're seeing this too. Was there any fix? Is it an issue with the Open Hub table? We can see the tables listed, just can't preview any data.